# Reset arrow keys to default behaviour

Tags: javascript, scroll, accessibility, bing-maps

I notice my arrow keys have been hijacked by Bing map and is no longer scrolling the page.

Anyway to reset arrow keys to default behaviour by JavaScript?

Comment: so how do you suppose we answer this one? can you replicate the situation so everyone can see?

Comment: Disable javascript. Depending on the browser and installed extensions, you can selectively disabled scripts.

Comment: Disabling JavaScript is not an option as with most websites of today. To replicate, just add bing map to any web page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I found the keydown event for bing which could be used. So what happens is, user can still zoom in and out/ click-drag to pan when their cursor is within the bing map (which doesn't take up the whole page). However, when they keydown on the arrow keys for the site in general, this should not affect the bing map.

After initialising new Microsoft.Maps, I found that I can add a handler to cancel the keydown event for the map:

```
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'keydown', cancelEvent)
```

Comment: Thanks. How did you figure out the API call?

Comment: I went looking for the keydown handler (which must exist for the behaviour to persist) and found the documentation to cancel it. Much preferred to trying to overwrite (aka hack) a solution.

Comment: I tried this answer, and it works, but it seems to cause other problems where it still messes with keydown events outside of the maps plugin. I found a better approach is to set disableKeyboardInput: true in mapOptions. Another option seems to be calling map.blur() after initializing if you still want keyboard input available on the map.

Answer (score 0):

Use [document.activeElement](http://my.opera.com/hallvors/blog/2007/05/16/quick-spec-for-ies-document-activeelement).blur() for Firefox, window.focus() for IE, and document.activeElement = document for Webkit to retake focus:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Blur Object Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<object id="bingmap" data="http://www.bing.com/maps"></object>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.activeElement.blur(); window.focus(); document.activeElement = document;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If Webkit is inconsistent, use a mouseover event instead:

```
function takeback()
    {
    while(RegExp("object","i").test(document.activeElement.nodeName) )
      {
      window.focus();
      document.activeElement.blur();
      }
    return false;
    }

  if (!!document.addEventListener)
    {
    document.addEventListener("mouseover", takeback, false);
    }
  else
    {
    window.focus();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Paul for the carefully thought out answer... I'll post what I used

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely prevent the map from interacting with keyboard events, I think the best solution is to use the "disableKeyboardInput" property when initializing the map.

```
  // Initialize the map
  map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("myMap"), {
   credentials:"Bing Maps Key",
   disableKeyboardInput: true
  });
```

From: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2807cbc3-0f88-4415-b2a9-09e950d210f7/issue-with-bing-maps-while-pressing-the-down-or-up-arrow

Answer (score 0):

To stop this behavior without breaking other JavaScript (i.e. removing keybinds but preserving other page functionality), you need to break the specific JavaScript calls that affect keybinds (and only them).

The easiest way to do this is with GreaseMonkey and a pre-made script like this one: [Disable website keyboard hooks](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/5819-disable-website-keyboard-hooks)